How to solve a dynamic import in all CommonJS modules. (Electron-Store)
I'm developing a desktop application with Electron, and I have a problem with local data storage. My goal is to check if the user is already logged in using a locally stored token. If the token exists, the application should directly open the main window. Otherwise, it should first display a loading window and a login window (console.log("Token is Null")).
However, when I try to import the electron-store library, I get an error.
const Store = require('electron-store');
const store = new Store();

let mainWindow;

function createMainWindow(alrealdyLogin) {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        frame: false,
        show: true,
        transparent: false,
        resizable: false,
        fullscreenable: false,
        titleBarStyle: 'customButtonsOnHover',
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            contextIsolation: true,
            enableRemoteModule: false,
            nodeIntegration: false
        },
        icon: path.join(__dirname, 'icon.png')


    });

    mainWindow.loadFile('html/loading.html');
}

app.on('ready', () => {
    const token = store.get('token');

    if (token) {
        createLoginWindow(false);
        createMainWindow();
    } else {
        createLoadingWindow(true);
        createLoginWindow();
    }
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) token == null ? console.log("Token is Null") : createMainWindow();
});

The error:

App threw an error during load Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Narzay\Projets\Meagan Client\Launcher Electron\node_modules\electron-store\index.js from C:\Users\Narzay\Projets\Meagan Client\Launcher Electron\main.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\Narzay\Projets\Meagan Client\Launcher Electron\main.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
at c._load (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:16955)
at Object. (C:\Users\Narzay\Projets\Meagan Client\Launcher Electron\main.js:3:15)

Alert Pop-Up:

A JavaScript error occurred in the main process


Uncaught Exception:


Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Narzay\Projets\Meagan Client\Launcher Electron\node_modules\electron-store\index.js from
C:\Users\Narzay\Projets\Meagan Client\Launcher Electron\main.js not supported. Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\Narzay\Projets\Meagan Client\Launcher Electron\main.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
at c._load (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:16955)
at Object. (C:\Users\Narzay\Projets\Meagan Client\Launcher
Electron\main.js:3:15)

I would like to recover the "token" value in the "localStorage":
localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);

Did you try what the error message suggests?

I had an issue like that with one of the libraries I used at work and dynamic import was not an option. In the end I decided to wrap it up in a custom package which was than imported by main project. In the package I exported things I needed and built it using esbuild with --format cjs option. Then I could import this package in the actual project using npm workspaces. Let me know if you would like more details on that. You can also see brief explaination here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-admin-client/issues/523#issuecomment-1273231149

Yes I do them but I still get errors.

I finally use "keytar"

Just change this:
const Store = require('electron-store');

to this:
const Store = ( await import('electron-store') ).default;

The error is pretty much self explanatory and provides a the solution.

I did what the error told me before posting but unfortunately every time I do what it says I still get problems :
`const Store = ( await import('electron-store') ).default;
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'import'`

I finally use "keytar"

If you want to store a connection token, use "keytar", it's more secure.
const keytar = require('keytar');
And use this like this :
await keytar.setPassword('app-id', 'authToken', token);
and :
await keytar.getPassword('app-id', 'authToken');
